# Python How to convert pyaudio bytes into virtual file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyaudio, wave

### In Short

Is there a way to convert raw audio data (obtained by `PyAudio` module) into the form of virtual file (can be obtained by using python `open()` function), without saving it to the disk and read it from the disk? Details are provided as belows.

### What Am I Doing

I'm using `PyAudio` to record audio, then it will be fed into a tensorflow model to get prediction. Currently, it works when I firstly save the recorded sound as `.wav` file on the disk, and then read it again to feed it into the model. Here is the code of recording and saving:

```py
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK_LENGTH = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
RECORD_SECONDS = 1

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_LENGTH)

print("* recording")
frames = [stream.read(RATE * RECORD_SECONDS)]  # here is the recorded data, in the form of list of bytes
print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

After I get the raw audio data (variable `frames`), it can be saved by using python `wave` module as belows. We can see that when saving, some meta message must be saved by calling functions like `wf.setxxx`.

```py
import os

output_dir = "data/"
output_path = output_dir + "{:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.wav".format(datetime.now())

if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# save the recorded data as wav file using python `wave` module
wf = wave.open(output_path, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

And here is the code of using the saved file to run inference on tensorflow model. It just simply read it as binary then the model will handle the rest.

```py
import classifier  # my tensorflow model

with open(output_path, 'rb') as f:
    w = f.read()
    classifier.run_graph(w, labels, 5)
```

### THE PROBLEM

For real-time needs, I need to keep streaming the audio and feeding it into the model once a while. But **it seems unreasonable to keep saving the file on the disk and then read it again and again**, which will spend losts of time on I/O.

I want to **keep the data in memeory and use it directly**, rather than saving and reading it repeatedly. However, python `wave` module does not support reading and writing simultaneously (refers [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html)).

If I directly feed the data without some meta data (e.g. channels, frame rate) (which can be added by `wave` module during saving) like this:

```py
w = b''.join(frames)
classifier.run_graph(w, labels, 5)
```

I will get error as belows:

```
2021-04-07 11:05:08.228544: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1651] OP_REQUIRES failed at decode_wav_op.cc:55 : Invalid argument: Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found
```

The tensorflow model I'm using is provided here: [ML-KWS-for-MCU](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-KWS-for-MCU), hope this helps.
Here is the code that produces the error: (`classifier.run_graph()`)

```py
def run_graph(wav_data, labels, num_top_predictions):
    """Runs the audio data through the graph and prints predictions."""
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #   Feed the audio data as input to the graph.
        #   predictions  will contain a two-dimensional array, where one
        #   dimension represents the input image count, and the other has
        #   predictions per class
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("labels_softmax:0")
        predictions, = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {"wav_data:0": wav_data})

        # Sort to show labels in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions.argsort()[-num_top_predictions:][::-1]
        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = labels[node_id]
            score = predictions[node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        return 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using a BytesIO object?

Comment: @MadPhysicist If you mean wrapping the data with `io.BytesIO()`, tensorflow says `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unsupported object type _io.BytesIO`

Comment: Did you rewind the file before using?

Comment: Post how you got the error exactly. Tensorflow seems to work fine with io.BytesIO in general.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Posted. I am not familiar with tensorflow, and I only know it requires wav data, whose type is bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use io.BytesIO instead of a physical file, they share the same interface but BytesIO is only kept in memory:

```
import io
container = io.BytesIO()
wf = wave.open(container, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(4)
wf.setsampwidth(4)
wf.setframerate(4)
wf.writeframes(b'abcdef')

# Read the data up to this point
container.seek(0)
data_package = container.read()

# add some more data...
wf.writeframes(b'ghijk')

# read the data added since last
container.seek(len(data_package))
data_package = container.read()
```

This should allow you to continuously stream the data into the file while reading the excess using your TensorFlow code.

Comment: It solves my problem exactly, appreciate a lot! :D

Comment: For a real-time application, we need to wrap part of the answer above to a while loop. Do I understand it correctly?